# counting elements in a specific dataframe.iloc

Tags: python, pandas

I have a feature that only consist of binary Values (0,1). I'm trying to count the number of occurrences of each binary value in a single column or feature.

Code:

```
df   = pd.read_csv(training_file)
data = df.iloc[:, 2]

#This only returns the size of the column and not sure why
print(data.count())
```

Is there a way with panda to only return the number of occurrence for a specific value like 0?

Comment: You should be able to use value_counts as described here :https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html

Comment: Does pandas `value_counts()` work for you ? --> https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html

Comment: @Horbaje @dzakyputra i attempted to use that however i was not able to figure out what  the number of occurrence reflects. For example if ```finish = data.value(counts)``` then ```print(finish[0])``` it would return the occurrence but not sure which element it reflects

Comment: @STOPIMACODER - Your solution si correct, `print(finish[0])` return number of 0 values, `print(finish[1])` number of `1` values, verify with `sum` - data.sum()

Comment: Try the following and see if it solves your problem: data[column_name].value_counts().index.tolist()

Comment: Both solutions work perfectly! Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

You can use data.sum() if the type in the column is not string especially because the data is binary (0,1).